# Why can I not create a directory using php?

Tags: php, forms, directory, mkdir

I have a form where users can upload an image. I have another page which already works that then creates a directory and places the image in it. For some reason, when I copy that same code to my current page, it gives me the following error:

> **Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /home5/ideapale/public_html/amatorders_final/user_char_upload.php
>   on line 251**

Here is the code it is referring to:

```
if (!file_exists("../upload/" . $order_id . '_' . $row['last_name'])) { //Checks if the directory already exists
    mkdir("../upload/" . $order_id . '_' . $row['last_name'], 0755); //Creates a new directory with the order_id and Customer last name
}
```

I tried echoing out all those variables, so I know they work.

It seems pretty straighforward to me, so i'm not sure why the mkdir function isn't working for me on this page. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [**`mkdir`**](https://www.php.net/mkdir) with two parameters, in order to create the directory `a/b/c`, the directory `a/b` must exist.

If you want `a/b` to be created when you try to create `a/b/c`, you need to pass `true` as a third parameter *(the one called `recursive` ;-) )* to [**`mkdir`**](https://www.php.net/mkdir).

If you `upload` directory already exists, then, you need to make sure that `../upload/` is actually what you think.

This `../upload/` is relative to the current directory of execution *(which is not necessarily the same as the one that contains your script !)*

You might want to try using this :

```
var_dump(realpath('../upload/'));
```

to check if that directory is what you think -- it'll display its full path if it exists ; or false if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed that problem, but now I get this error: [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Comment: Youy're welcome :-) ;; well, that's another problem : you are trying to move a file to a remote location, or something like that ? *(Eventually, as that's a distinct problem, you might want to ask a different question, with code sample and all)*

Answer (score 0):

```
you are passing wrong path to the function man.
```

i.e move_upload_file($arg);

If u give wrong path in $arg,it will show the error msg as u said.